# Module build failed ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular

I have upgraded my application from angular 4 to angular 6. I am getting the following error. I have already added the include files in the tsConfig. I am getting the error while running ng test. I wonder why it is complaining of a file under @wtw folder when it is included in the tsConfig

```
"include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./node_modules/@wtw/**/*",
     "./node_modules/@types/**/*"
  ]
```

Error message

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@wtw/platform/services/index.ts
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\vstsprojects\testproject\testproject.ClientSide\node_modules\@wtw\platform\services\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please
make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an
issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format .
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\vstsprojects\testproject\testproject.ClientSide\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\packages\ngtools\webpac
k\src\angular_compiler_plugin.ts:988:15)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\vstsprojects\testproject\testproject.ClientSide\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\packages\ngtools\webpack\src\loader.ts:49:29
)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 @ ./src/app/effects/risk-portfolio/risk-portfolio.effect.spec.ts 5:17-50
 @ ./src sync \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts
```

tsConfig

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "type-definition"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },

  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./node_modules/@wtw/**/*",
     "./node_modules/@types/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the official guide? https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Yes i have followed

Comment: is it got to do with ordering of files in the tsconfig. I have removed the include section from tsconfig and instead added it now to tsapp.config

Comment: Following are the entries    "./node_modules/@wtw/platform/services/index.ts",
     "./node_modules/@wtw/platform/tests/stubs/index.ts",
     "./node_modules/@wtw/toolkit/index.ts",
    "./node_modules/@wtw/**/*",
     "./node_modules/@types/**/*",
     "./src/main.ts",
    "./src/polyfills.ts",
    "./src/**/*"

Answer (score 5):

i got same error,in your app.routing.ts file , check routing path of lazy modules
check your component name and correct the lowercase or uppercase in the path, exacactly.

Answer (score 3):

Just try creating one angular 6 project and cross verify your files. Just cross check below files and see if it helps

In tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

In tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

In tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where does the tsconfig.spec.json file go? @Krishna

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens when file case does not match. For an example, i had a folder called **layout** with `layout-dashboard.ts` inside. In my import path had the following path which resulted in an error. `import { DashboardLayoutComponent } from '../Layout/dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.component';` of which the correct path is this one, `import { DashboardLayoutComponent } from '../layout/dashboard-layout/dashboard-layout.component';` what you need to notice is that the first doesnt give any path related error. What i can say is the angular folders are case sensitive. layout != Layout

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error after I upgraded from Angular 7 to Angular 8 and needed to [update my dist structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview#heading=h.k0mh3o8u5hx). The easiest way is to just use [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) in that case. Very simple setup!

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that my tsconfig.app.json has the path /src/tsconfig.app.json and my tsconfig.json has /tsconfig.json and I changed my tsconfig.app.json from

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

to

```
"include": [    
    "../**/*.d.ts"
]
```