# Angular 10 Error : Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an application on angular 10. I tried to edit app.routing.module.ts file, setting path and component. From then on I am getting this error below:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/accessories/accessories.component.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\Users\user\Apps\Angular\PhoneStore\src\app\accessories\accessories.component.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.     
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\user\Apps\Angular\PhoneStore\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:949:23)
    at C:\Users\user\Apps\Angular\PhoneStore\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: This fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54094177/2509290