# Getting ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts Module build failed while running ng test - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Somehow karma.config was missed in the existing angular project I am working with.

So I have added it manually and tried to run the test using the command `ng test`

While running the following error is displayed.

```
[./src/polyfills.ts] 699 bytes {polyfills} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[./src/test.ts] 990 bytes {main}
    + 228 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Projects\MyProject\src\polyfills.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\C:\Projects\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\packages\ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.ts:982:15)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Projects\MyProject\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\packages\ngtools\webpack\src\loader.ts:49:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ multi ./src/polyfills.ts
```

I notice there are two tsconfig.json in the app,
The first one is present under the project root folder and the content

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The second one is present inside the src folder and the content is

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

I have tried to use include in any of those files to add src/polyfills.ts but no luck.

Can anyone guide how to fix this?

Angular version - 6

Comment: I am still waiting for the answer, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found tsconfig.spec.json did not have `polyfills.ts`. So I have added it as below and the issue was resolved

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

This post: [Module build failed ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446988/module-build-failed-ts-is-missing-from-the-typescript-compilation-please-make-s/52481452) helped me to validate the contents of tsconfig.json,tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json.